# Is chi-square appropriate for this data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion

I have data as shown in the picture below where the column, 'school' is the site of the data; 'grp' is indicative of either control(C) or experimental(E); 'tStu' is the number of students. The next four are count data. And the last four columns are just the fractions of the count data.
I have to do statistical testing between the two groups control(C) and experimental(E) for the count data.
The internet is pointing me towards chi-square test but I am not sure whether it is appropriate or how to proceed further with statistical testing.
Any help will be useful for my novice mind!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an experiment where interventions are assigned by cluster (school). Of they were assigned in a randomized fashion, it's a cluster randomized trial, which would simplify the analysis (you do not need to worry about the rather choice being based on expected outcomes). There are whole books on this topic (e.g. "Cluster Randomised Trials" by Hayes and Moulton). It seems e.g. a model (e.g. ANCOVA or non parametric) on the summary outcomes by cluster works well for few clusters, while with many clusters a mixed effects model with a random cluster effect (e.g. logistic regression) is a good choice.

Comment: so i have three samples for a count data in each group...not sure how logistic regression would help

Comment: Depends on what these counts are: $y_i$ out of $n_i$ students achieving some particular exam result screams for logistic regression. Something like number of incidents of fist fights might be more Poisson or negative binomial regression.